# How can I calculate the size of hive table with specific partitions filter?

Tags: bash, hive

Background.
I can calculate size of my hive partitioned table like below. <i.e. finding size of all partition and then sum-up sizes of needed partitions>

```
hdfs dfs -du 'hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1'
100   hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1/dt=2021-10-06
200   hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1/dt=2021-10-07
300   hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1/dt=2021-10-08
400   hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1/dt=2021-10-09
500   hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1/dt=2021-10-10
600   hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1/dt=2021-10-11
```

I want to find out size of table between specific partitions <i.e. dt >= 2021-10-09 >

i.e. size of test.tbl1 between dt=2021-10-09 to dt=2021-10-11 partitions is = 400+500+600 = 1500 Bytes

Is there any way to filter out result during dfs -du phase to avoid manual summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a POSIX awk (e.g. GNU or BSD awk) you can pre-process the last field (`$NF`) of each line with the `gsub` function to keep only the date. You can then compute the sum of the first field (`$1`) if and only if the last field (`$NF`) is in a defined range. Example for `dt >= 2021-10-09`:

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -du 'hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1' |
  awk -v dtmin='2021-10-09' '
    {gsub(/.*=/,"",$NF)} $NF>=dtmin{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'
1500
```

For a closed range:

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -du 'hdfs://localhost:9090/user/temp/warehouse/test.db/tbl1' |
  awk -v dtmin='2021-10-06' -v dtmax='2021-10-08' '
    {gsub(/.*=/,"",$NF)} $NF>=dtmin && $NF<=dtmax{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'
600
```